# disable_with can not work in table tag?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my form

```
   <table>
    <%= form_for Slot.new, :url => slots_path(@current_webclass), :validate => true, remote: true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal', id: 'slot-form', data: {type: "script", method: :post}} do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'timepicker' %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :start_at, class: 'timepicker' %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <%= f.submit 'add', class: 'btn btn-success', disable_with: "process..." %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as a symbol `button_tag "Checkout", :disable_with => "Please wait..."`

If that doesn't work try using:

'btn btn-success', disable_with => "process..."} %>